# JSON_VALUE on Azure Sql Data Warehouse : 'JSON_VALUE' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: json, azure-synapse

JSON_VALUE() does not work on Azure SQL Data Warehouse even if the compatibility level is 130.

Despite having the compatility_level set to 130, it seems that I cannot have the JSON_VALUE working on Azure SQL Data Warehouse.
ref: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.test (
    doc_name        VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    code            VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    currentState_id INT NULL,
    json_doc        NVARCHAR(MAX)  null ) WITH (
    DISTRIBUTION = HASH ( doc_name ), 
    CLUSTERED INDEX ( doc_name ASC ) );

insert into dbo.test ([doc_name],[code],[currentState_id],[json_doc])  values ('doc1.txt','doc1',1,'{"one":"value1","two":"value2"}');

select JSON_VALUE(json_doc,'$.one') from dbo.test where code = 'doc1';
--  Msg 104162, Level 16, State 1, Line 17 
-- 'JSON_VALUE' is not a recognized built-in function name. SELECT compatibility_level FROM SYS.databases where name = my_DW';
-- returns 130
```

From what I understand, according to the documentation, JSON_VALUE should work on Azure SQL Data Warehouse if the compatibility level is 130.

Comment: So switched to a database that has compatibility_level to 140 and it worked. However, can't change the compatibility level of my database to 140. "ALTER DATABASE [my_DW] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 140 GO", returns Parse error at line: 2, column: 27: Incorrect syntax near '140'.

Comment: It’s supposed to be available in preview now. Maybe open an Azure support case? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-sql-data-warehouse-releases-new-capabilities-for-performance-and-security/

Comment: @GregGalloway Your comment and the link provided was what I needed to find the cause of my problem.  Running `SELECT @@VERSION AS 'SQL Data Warehouse';` revealed that my data warehouse is still in **Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse - 10.0.9999.0 Apr 9 2019 06:29:14 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation**.

Comment: I would be curious if pause and resume would get you the latest build

Comment: The JSON functions worked for me today with a warehouse I created last month.  Version number the same, but different date!?  `Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse - 10.0.9999.0 May 30 2019`.

Comment: @GregGalloway Yes it did get me the build.  8 hours of work that could have been prevented by 8 minutes needed to pause an resume.

Answer (score 0):

As at 8th May 2019, JSON_VALUE does work in Azure SQL Data Warehouse

See the main announcement [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/updates/json-data-support-for-azure-sql-data-warehouse-is-now-in-preview/).

My results from a live test today with your query in Azure SQL Data Warehouse:
[image: My Results]